# Parsing text with javascript: mysteriously generated paragraph tags

Tags: javascript, text

When I parse text in js and want to retrieve a (DNA sequence) query name from multiple lines and put that between paragraph tags, it wont work correctly.

(Part of) **The text file:**

```
Database: db 
       22,774 sequences; 12,448,185 total letters

Searching..................................................done

Query= gi|998623327|dbj|LC126440.1| Rhodosporidium sp. 14Y315 genes
for ITS1, 5.8S rRNA, ITS2, partial and complete sequence
     (591 letters)

                                                                 Score    E
Sequences producing significant alignments:                      (bits) Value
```

**The code:**
(I read the lines into an array first)

```
    for(var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++){
        var line = lines[i];

        if(line.search("Query= ") != -1){ 
            results.innerHTML += "    <p class='result_name'>    <br>Result name: ";
            //the name starts at 7th char
            results.innerHTML += line.slice(7);
            //take the next line
            i++;
            // tried to searh for "\n" or "\r" or "\r\n" to end cycle - didn't work
            // so instead I put this for the while condition:
            while(lines[i].length > 2 ){
                results.innerHTML += lines[i];
                i++;
            }
            //here is where I want the result_name paragraph to end.
            results.innerHTML += "    </p>    <p>Result(s):</p>";
        }
     }
```

**The result:**
[image: Result]

Comment: try change <br> tag by <br/>

Comment: changing AND removing <br> tag didn't help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use

```
innerHTML +=
```

Generate your whole HTML before hand and then add it to the innerHTML, my guess is that when you use innerHTML, the browser add end tag automatically.

Comment: Yes, this was indeed the case, thank you! It worked. :) Also, could somebody tell me why I couldn't  end my while cycle by looking for newline symbol?

Comment: end of lines statements may contains either \n, or \r\n, or \r as a end of line. So you may have trouble with only testing \n. Try to "\r\n" || "\n" || "\r"

Comment: what about lines[i].indexOf("\n") < 2 ? this is quite ugly but this should do the trick (i don't think the \r alone case is really relevant)

Comment: Ugh, I'm gonna quit and stick with just checking the length of the line, irregardless the content. That works. Thanks for all the trouble!

Answer (score 1):

Filling innerHTML with a partial html will be auto-corrected with the end tags. So, Create a temporary variable to collect your string and fill it in the destination at once as below. that fixes the issue

```
var temp = "";
for(var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++){
var line = lines[i];

    if(line.search("Query= ") != -1){ 
        temp += "    <p class='result_name'>    <br>Result name: ";
        //the name starts at 7th char
        temp += line.slice(7);
        //take the next line
        i++;
        // tried to searh for "\n" or "\r" or "\r\n" to end cycle - didn't work
        // so instead I put this for the while condition:
        while(lines[i].length > 2 ){
           temp += lines[i];
           i++;
        }
        //here is where I want the result_name paragraph to end.
        temp += "    </p>    <p>Result(s):</p>";
    }
}
results.innerHTML = temp;
```

Comment: Yes you are correct, thank you. ( @Walfrat was faster with his anwser)